# OS on external hard drive

Tags: mount, permissions, security

If I put a OS like Ubuntu onto a external hard drive, would it allow viruses to infect my internal hard drive? If more info is needed, then feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you narrow the scope of the question? It is kinda broad question.

Comment: @RodrigoArgumedo The scope of the question doesn't much matter, since it's completely [off-topic](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This isn't the right place for this. However, it is technically possible, although very unlikely. Basically, you'd have to contract a linux malware (which are very rare to begin with) that's sosphisticated enough to mount your internal drive, if it isn't already mounted, and then have enough knowledge of windows (or whatever is on the interal drive) to start messing with files on your internal drive. Some sort of deletions would probably be most common, and easy to implement. But again, this would be extremely rare.

Comment: Ok thank you @user979616 and I'm sorry for it being off topic.

Comment: It kind of does matter: do we migrate? We should never migrate crap. In this case, I think the question is specific enough; migrating to [ubuntu.SE].

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter from what location you boot Ubuntu from and in what location you have drives with other data partitions. As long as it's connected, it's accessible.

I'm now describing the possibilities. Probably the likeliness of infecting your Ubuntu system with malware that is capable of performing all those tasks is very close to zero, but it would be technically possible.

**Theoretically possible attacking scenarios:**

Let's first assume the easiest situation for malware: You have mounted the file systems on the internal Windows (? I assume this, but it doesn't matter) somewhere. This allows every program to access (read and write, depending on your mount options you might also restrict that though) all files on the mounted device simply by their path. Programs can/do usually not distinguish between data from different disks as Linux systems mount all partitions into the same virtual file system tree structure. So it's just like the files were on your Ubuntu drive. No difference as soon as it's mounted. The risk of damage is pretty high.

The other possible situation is that you did not mount the Windows partitions from Ubuntu. In that case no application (including malware of course) running as normal user can access the files there. To mount the partition root privileges are required, so that would be impossible as well unless you voluntarily enter your password in the wrong place. As long as you don't enter your admin password or run any possibly infected software as root, your Windows data is pretty safe.

But how would the situation change if either the malware you get is smart enough to bypass Ubuntu's user privilege restrictions and become root by itself or if you accidentally give it your admin password or manually run it as root? In that case the application can not only mount all available drives to access the contained file systems and do whatever it wants with the data there (steal data, delete or overwrite data, install other malware), it can also get direct read/write access to all connected raw disks and partitions without mounting them. This raw disk access is pretty useless to steal your data or modify something to inject other malware to your Windows system (unless it ships its own NTFS/other file system driver), but it is perfectly enough to make a data massacre and simply overwrite or format the entire partition or disk. This is an extreme risk for all your data on any connected device!

**Conclusion:**

Software running under your normal account without root privileges can only damage data on *unmounted* devices/partitions if it is smart enough to exploit a not yet discovered and fixed security vulnerability in the Ubuntu system to cause a privilege escalation and become root without user interaction. You can protect yourself from this pretty unlikely case vary well by always installing all available software updates as soon as they get released. The risk that you yourself grant a malicious application root access by simply entering your password where you should not have done so is much higher. Be vigilant.

Data on a *mounted* device/partition is always in danger. Usually you mount the partition in a way so that your user account has full read/write access. So all applications you run can do the same, including malware.

If a malicious application somehow manages to run as root (by tricking you to enter the admin password or rarely by exploiting a vulnerability), there's nothing that can stop it from accessing all physically connected devices. It can either mount them and read/write access the containing file systems to get to your data or it can simply access the raw partition/disk and just format or overwrite it to harm you. Whatever runs as root on your system has ultimate powers over everything connected to the computer.

**How to protect myself?**

- Never enter your admin password in a password prompt you did not expect!
- Always install the available updates as soon as possible.
- Never install software or run scripts from untrusted sources.
  The official Ubuntu repositories can be trusted, third party PPAs are usually safe (especially those maintained by well known teams) but are not necessarily checked. Remember that everybody can create a PPA. `.deb` packages downloaded from any arbitrary online source are highly insecure.
- Never run anything as root that you do not ultimately trust.
- Avoid doing anything as root wherever possible. Prefer a restricted user account for daily use over your admin account.
- When you have to operate as root, do that using `sudo` or similar tools, do not log in as root.
- When you have to run interactive applications as root (such as your files manager or an editor) try to keep the session as short as possible to avoid accidentally performing other tasks as root.